# How to fix docker container autocompletion

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on many machines in the past and auto-completion always had just worked out of the box. Strangely, in a new docker install on an *Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)* virtual machine, when I press tab, nothing happens. I tried it on my WSL terminal, and if I type `sudo docker start g` and then tab, it autocompletes to `sudo docker start gifted_hofstadter`. Yet, both *only* have these two files in:

```
# ls /etc/bash_completion.d/
apport_completion  git-prompt
```

So I don't understand why I would have to add a `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker` file as an [article](https://linuxconfig.org/tab-does-not-automatically-complete-docker-commands-solution) suggests. How do I fix it with minimal changes? To be clear, regular bash autocompletion works fine, the issue is specific to docker. Thanks.

**Update**: Installed [podman](https://podman.io/blogs/2021/06/16/install-podman-on-ubuntu.html) and the same autocomplete issue exists although I don't think it's related.

I copied [this docker.sh](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/boardstretcher/241e14094b2bd5440735/raw/e81a7b2de0ea7259f13be2b982db5dc714f8da09/docker.sh) file to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and restarted the shell. Now docker commands autocomplete, e.g. `docker sta [tab]` expands to `docker start`. Also if I do `docker start f` it expands to `docker start f36da5e5a9a8` i.e. the container ID.

However, it won't expand the container name, such as `frosty_tu` when I do `docker start fro [tab]`. While I appreciate the solution, this is another reason I don't want to shop around for third party scripts and prefer the out-of-the-box experience I have seen on new installs before.

After an upgrade, the issue remains on "Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS".

I'm using `Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086349` installed with `snap`.

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu 20 LTS

Comment: That's correct. Was writing from memory in a rush and thought that the approximate, i.e. major (YY) version, was enough. Updated with the full version, thanks.

Comment: Completion scripts are located under `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`. You should state how you installed Docker, there are at least 3 different options: 1) Snap, 2) Default APT, and 3) APT from Docker repos. I've installed Docker using method 3 (Docker repos), and my autocompletion works with container names, but not with container ID.

Comment: Funny coincidence, I had actually just thought of comparing docker's snap vs the one from the default APT, i.e. 1) and 2) from your list, after running twice on a [docker cp](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/564) snap bug. I see this issue on two servers with snap's docker. Not sure what my previous WSL (which had good docker autocompletion) had as I have a new one with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS without docker yet. Will try 1) and 2) there and update accordingly. By the way, it is the container name autocompletion I care about.

Comment: It seems that APT no longer has even an ancient version of docker and the [docker install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) reminded me of why I went with the convenience of `snap`. And I forgot that *snap* isn't available on WSL. Anyway, I'll probably try switching at some point, but for now, I need my containers already created with snap, and not too keen on making a switch without being sure it will solve the issue. Updated the question to mention that I am using snap, thanks.

Comment: Try my solution. If it works for you, just upvote and choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: `source` the (right) script!

The docker script I mentioned in my question is not the official one.
I just noticed that last year I placed a file (which I called `docker`) under `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. The script has the following comments:

```bash
# To enable the completions either:
#  - place this file in /etc/bash_completion.d
#  or
#  - copy this file to e.g. ~/.docker-completion.sh and add the line
#    below to your .bashrc after bash completion features are loaded
#    . ~/.docker-completion.sh
```

So I had the first option, but that wasn't enough to get the autocompletion to work.

It was only after I tried `source` today that I saw a good result. I didn't want to clutter my home directory so I just left it there and added this to my `.bashrc`:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/docker
```

Happy to report that now container name autocompletion works as expected! Thanks to @Artur Meinild for prompting me to look at this again.

**Getting The Right Script**

The script distributed with *snap* is just a symlink to a script that in my experience won't do the job:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker -> /snap/snapd/current/usr/lib/snapd/complete.sh
```

I copied the `docker` script referenced above from a previous Ubuntu WSL install (where autocompletion worked) but there's a [similar one](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker) on docker's github repository. If you installed docker from snap, I'd suggest downloading and trying that one.

**Autocomplete Container IDs**

As documented in the script, if you want to also autocomplete container IDs, just set the environment variable:

```
DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_CONTAINER_IDS=yes
```

This can be done on demand on the same shell, or you can also add it to your `~/.bashrc` like I did.

Answer (score 0):

What I did as a solution was this:

1. Download bash-completion package if you don't have it: `sudo apt-get install bash-completion`
2. Download the docker bash completion from [this URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker) (it seems it's the most updated one): `sudo curl    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh`
3. **Important if you use a non-root user:** Add the current user (e.g. ubuntu) to the docker group: `sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu`
4. Logout & login again.

Step 2 is necessary, as it is mentioned in the script as:

> Note:
> Currently, the completions will not work if the docker daemon is not
> bound to the default communication port/socket
> If the docker daemon is using a unix socket for communication **your user
> must have access to the socket** for the completions to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is not shipping readily usable scripts, but rather a complex JSON payload containing the needed script. So you need to pipe the output by `wget` (or `curl` if you prefer) through `jq` tool in order to get it parsed.

The actual scriptlet that is working for me in my `.bashrc` looks like this one:

```
if hash docker &> /dev/null; then
  if [[ ! -f /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh ]]; then
    wget -q -O - https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker | jq -r .payload.blob.rawLines[] | sudo tee /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh &> /dev/null
    sudo chmod go+r /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh &> /dev/null
  fi
  source /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh
  export DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_CONTAINER_IDS=yes
fi
```

You can skip the line about `DOCKER_COMPLETION_SHOW_CONTAINER_IDS` variable is you don't want `kubectl` completion to include container IDs.

If for any reason you need to "refresh" your bash completion for kubectl, you just need to remove the current script and re-resource your `.bashrc` ( or whatever file you have put the above code in):

```
sudo rm -f /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Of course, you need to install the `bash-completion` package with `apt` if you don't have it already.

I tweaked this answer from the above ones plus some searching and testing of mine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to enable programmable completion features in `.~/.bashrc` (or add in the very bottom)

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable 
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```